# Eclipse 2022-09 MessageDialog error in E4 Handler

Tags: eclipse, swt, e4

```java
public void execute(Shell shell, @Named(IServiceConstants.ACTIVE_PART) MPart aPart,
            @Named(IServiceConstants.ACTIVE_SELECTION) @Optional List<?> selection) {

MessageDialog.openError(shell, "Error", "test");
```

Below error occurred when dialog ok button click.

also Everything dialog is the same.

It only happens in the eclipse 2022-09 version.

please help me.

```
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Widget is disposed
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4918)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4833)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4804)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Widget.java:450)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.checkWidget(Widget.java:369)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button.getSelection(Button.java:623)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.dom.ButtonElement$1.widgetSelected(ButtonElement.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:252)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4251)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1066)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4068)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3645)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:823)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:799)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.MessageDialog.open(MessageDialog.java:609)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.MessageDialog.open(MessageDialog.java:405)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.MessageDialog.openError(MessageDialog.java:491)
```

Comment: That looks like a button in the `ButtonElement` code in the CSS support.  There appears to be a fix for it in the M2 build of Eclipse 2022-12. Are you doing CSS styling on dialog buttons?

Comment: thanks greg.  My doubts have been resolved. I thought there was a problem in 2022-09 version. We look forward to the next update. e4 use the css style.